# How to keep the collapse/expand both in row group and column group in ssrs 2008 r2 when exported to excel?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have main report with two subreports: 1. Sales 2. Monthly Data.

- Sales(subreport) has collapse/expand on row grouping
- Monthly Data(subreport) have row grouping and expand/collapse column grouping.

Both subreports can render the expand/collapse when exported to excel individually.

Now, the problem is when I exported the report to excel through the main report which calls both the subreport only the monthly data report has expand/collapse only...in addition to this, the expand/collapsed is visible in report preview for both the subreport when I preview it through my main report.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. The data from the Sales subreport is visible when exported but has only the toggle function/button missing? Could you maybe add screenshots of whats happening?